Iterating through file lines and changing variable elements of each line
I want to open some .dat file. Read each line and find a value then change the value then move to next line. Then save everything to an .out file.
I was able to do this with an if i == (line #) for each line before, but now the file has over 1000 lines and I'd rather not write individual if statements for every index.
The problem I keep getting is that it will enumerate through each line, but it will not loop through my strings of searching variables and replace variables.
Example of in.dat
100   200   400   80
100   205   305   90
109   207   307   85

string_cs is a list containing strings like 109, 203, 406
I want to replace 400 with 109, then 305 with 203, then 307 with 406 and so on. Unfortunately, the .dat file has 18 rows in the beginning before the data with information so I can't just print the data out into column frames.
for k in chan:
    with open('in.dat') as fin:
        with open(f'out.dat', 'w') as fout:
            for i, line in enumerate(fin, 1):
                for l,j in zip(string_cs, chan):
                    if str(l) in line:
                        modified = line.replace(str(l), str(j), 1)
                        fout.write(modified)
                    else:
                        fout.write(line)


what is string_cs?. Also, you might want to dedent your fout.write to be outside the for l,j in  loop

In addition to string_cs can you please edit your question to include samples of what is contained in in.dat and chan?

For issues like this getting familiar with your editor's debugger can help a lot. I personally use Spyder IDE, which allows you to step line by line through your code, and inspect the live variables. This can go a long way to help you understand what's going on.

but it will not loop through my strings of searching variables and replace variables What exactly do you mean?  The loop looks okay to me -- how do you know it's not looping?  What actual behavior do you see, that tells you it isn't looping?

It would help a lot if you provided sample data for the input file, and string_cs and chan.

What's the purpose of the outer for k in chan loop? k is never used. Also, you should probably write the line only after all the changes have been applied.

string_cs is a new list of variables that I want to insert. for k in chan is used because I need to continuously create new .out files.

This is a bit of a guess, since I don't know exactly what your files and changes-lists look like, but try this:
with open('in.dat') as fin, open('out.dat', 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        for l, j in zip(string_cs, chan):
            line = line.replace(l, j)
        fout.write(line)

The main changes are (i) call line.replace without third param 1 so it replaces all occurances of the string (if that's that you want), and (ii) write the line to fout only after all the replacements have been applied, not after each one of them.
Also, the outermost loop did not seem to serve any purpose, and neither did the enumerate. Also, assuming the elements in your changes-lists are strings, no conversion to str is needed, and neither is the if-in-line check (if it's not, replace just does nothing).

Update: Seeing your comment, it seems like the changes-list contains a different change for each line. In this case, you should zip those changes with the lines in the file!
with open('in.dat') as fin, open('out.dat', 'w') as fout:
    for line, l, j in zip(fin, string_cs, chan):
        fout.write(line.replace(l, j))

And if you want to skip the first 18 lines, you can use itertools.islice to skip the first 18 lines:
from itertools import islice
with open('in.dat') as fin, open('out.dat', 'w') as fout:
    for line, l, j in zip(islice(fin, 18, None), string_cs, chan):
        fout.write(line.replace(l, j))

... or call next(fin) in another loop before the main loop ...
with open('in.dat') as fin, open('out.dat', 'w') as fout:
    for _ in range(18):
        next(fin) # read and discard line
    for line, l, j in zip(fin, string_cs, chan):
        fout.write(line.replace(l, j))

... or, since zip itself is an iterator, you could also go back to the first version using enumerate and use next to get the next pair from the zip after the first 18 lines:
changes = zip(string_cs, chan)
with open('in.dat') as fin, open('out.dat', 'w') as fout:
    for i, line in enumerate(fin):
        if i < 18: continue # skip first 18 lines
        l, j = next(changes)
        fout.write(line.replace(l, j)


Thank you so much. In the in.dat file, I have 18 lines in the beginning that need to be skipped before I start replacing strings. That's why I was using enumerate so I could say if i > 18, do this. Is there another way to start at line 18?

You could also fast-forward the first 18 lines by calling next(fin)  18 times in a another loop before the actual for line in fin loop, but in that case just put the enumerate back in and do if i < 18: continue

I tried running your version and unfortunately it returned what I was getting before. It does go through each line, but it only finds the first string every time and replaces it with the first string every time. For example if the string is 0 and the replacement is 12, it goes through each line and finds a 0 and puts in 12. Instead I want to do that in line 1, then find a different string in line 2 and replace with a different string.

@allydewey See my edit.

Awesome! Do you know how to include enumerate within this? Or a way to get it to print the first 18 lines to out.dat then start the replacements?

@allydewey See edit for some alternatives.

Interestingly, it will now only print one line into the out.dat file. Not sure what is going on here. New problem as well, it replaces every string in the line. For example if the string is 0., it replaces every 0, but I want it to replace the 0. under the fourth column. I thought alternatively I could load the columns using np.loadtxt then replace one and put them back together, but not sure how to keep the 18 lines of header above because I still need it.

@allydewey Depending on what exactly you want to do (which has been rather vague so far) you could try a regex with word-boundary chars \b, or split and join the lines, or use the csv module...
